# ORMlite disable the read of a field

Tags: java, ormlite

I'm using ORMLITE with 2 Objects:

**User:**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "user")
public class    User {

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "id", generatedId = true, index = true)
    public int      id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true, foreignFieldName = "user")
    public Collection<File> files;
}
```

**File:**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "file")
public class    File {

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "id", generatedId = true, index = true)
    public int       id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "user", foreign = true) <- disable the read of this field
    public User          user;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "filename")
    public String        filename;

}
```

It's a One to Many, a "User" can have many "File". For accessing to the "Files", I always use the object "User" like that :

```
List<User>      users;
Dao<User, ?>    daoUser;

users = daoUser.queryForAll();
System.out.println(users);

System.out.println(users.files.get(0));
```

The object "User" inside the collection "File" is instantiated. I don't want !

I would like "`User.files.get(0).user`" to be null.

How can I disable the read of a Field on ORMLite ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to make one-to-many connection? 1 user may have many files?

Comment: Exactly. I have edited my question. Should be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The object "User" inside the collection "File" is instantiated. I don't want !
>
> How can I disable the read of a Field on ORMLite ?

You have a couple different ways of solving this.

1. You can have a `int user_id` field instead of a `User` field and then have a non-database field `User` that you hygrade from the database on your own from the `user_id`.
2. Another thing you can do is to use the `queryBuilder.selectColumns(...)` to select all of the columns *except* the `user_id` column.  If you don't return the `user_id` from the select then it won't instantiate a `User` instance.   It is important to note that if you mark the `user` field as being a `@DatabaseField`, [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) will change it to `user_id` or something.
3. You could use a `dao.queryForRaw(...)` method and a do the class translation yourself using your own `RawRowMapper` that ignores the `user_id` column in the results.

As an aside, may I ask *why* you don't want the `User` instantiated?  Is this a memory issue?

Comment: Thanks. It's for two reasons:
1/ I had a circular reference from GSON by Google
2/ It's for a REST. I don't want to have a reference of the user from the file when I read a user (I already know the user)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have error in your class definition, following classes make one-to-many connection.

Check the ormlite.com documentation, especially `eager` and `foreignAutoRefresh` parts.

**User:**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "user")
public class    User {

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "id", generatedId = true, index = true)
    public int      id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    public Collection<File> files;
}
```

**File:**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "file")
public class    File {

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "id", generatedId = true, index = true)
    public int       id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "id", foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = false)
    public User          user;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "filename")
    public String        filename;

}
```

Comment: With this code, "User" on the collection of "File" from "User" class is instantiated.